# GitHub Pages site will not load any theme other than minima

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages, jekyll-theme

#### Versions

Windows 10.0.19044.2364
ruby 3.1.3p185 (2022-11-24 revision 1a6b16756e) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
gem v3.3.26
jekyll 4.3.1

#### Problem

With my Gemfile and _config.yml in a default configuration using the *minima* theme, everything works as expected.  When I attempt to change to another theme (any theme), the site fails to load propertly.

#### Details

My default Gemfile:

```rb
source "https://rubygems.org"
# gem "jekyll", "~> 4.3.1"

# This is the default theme for new Jekyll sites. You may change this to anything you like.
gem "minima"

gem "github-pages", "~> 227", group: :jekyll_plugins

# If you have any plugins, put them here!
group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
  gem "jekyll-remote-theme"
end
...
```

My default _config.yml:

```yaml
title: default theme...
email: email@example.com
description: ...description...
domain: "chrisxfire.github.io"
url: "http://chrisxfire.github.io"

# Build settings
theme: minima

# remote-theme: pages-themes/midnight@v0.2.0
plugins:
- jekyll-feed
- jekyll-remote-theme
```

GitHub Pages generates the site correctly and the page is normal:

[image]

Next, I attempt to use a [GitHub Pages-supported theme](https://pages.github.com/themes/), like midnight.  I make the following changes:

In Gemfile, I change the line `gem "minima"` to:

```rb
gem "jekyll-theme-midnight"
```

In _config.yml, I change the line `theme: minima` to:

```yaml
theme: jekyll-theme-midnight
```

I then commit. GitHub Actions finish successfully, but I now have a blank white page on the site.

Next, per [the instructions on the midnight theme's GitHub site](https://github.com/pages-themes/midnight), I try making the following changes to _config.yml:

```yaml
# theme: jekyll-theme-midnight
remote-theme: pages-themes/midnight@v0.2.0
```

I then commit.  GitHub Actions finish successfully.  However, the page renders with only a blue header and nothing else:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should work as you described based on https://github.com/pages-themes/midnight and https://docs.github.com/en/pages/setting-up-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll/adding-a-theme-to-your-github-pages-site-using-jekyll

Comment: @Christian I will test locally and report back.  Repo = https://github.com/chrisxfire/chrisxfire.github.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

testing midnight theme... is your theme title.

To show the page in midnight black, I have moved your github-pages gem into plugins in the Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem "github-pages"
  gem "jekyll-feed", "~> 0.12"
  gem "jekyll-remote-theme"
end
```

Also, the current post and home layouts in pages and posts create warnings when starting the server. You should see them in the build log.

The theme is not required in your Gemfile anymore, as you use the remote-theme options in your _config.yml.

Comment: Fixed, see https://cadamini.github.io/chrisxfire.github.io/ - by adjusting page.layout and gem/config file, see https://github.com/chrisxfire/chrisxfire.github.io/pull/2

Comment: Thanks!  Can you help me understand why it was necessary to change `layout` from `page`/`post`/`home` to `default` in the markdown files?

Comment: Create a _layouts folder and put a html file in it, see official Jekyll docs or any theme GitHub page. The layout is rendering contained html plus the page content into a content variable (placeholder for it) in the layout

Comment: To answer your question, the theme only offers one default layout, see https://github.com/pages-themes/midnight/tree/master/_layouts

Answer (score 0):

In short - remove `layout: home`/`layout: page`/`layout: post` etc. (from `.markdown`/`.md` files) or change into `layout: default`, as it's the only one available in midnight theme (see: [midnight/_layouts](https://github.com/pages-themes/midnight/tree/master/_layouts)).

Using non-existent layout causes problems in displying page.

You can also see such warnings after executing `bundle exec jekyll serve`:

```
Build Warning: Layout 'post' requested in _posts/2023-11-24-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown does not exist.
Build Warning: Layout 'page' requested in about.markdown does not exist.
Build Warning: Layout 'home' requested in index.markdown does not exist.
Build Warning: Layout 'page' requested in markdown.MD does not exist.
```

If you want to have layouts like `home`, `page`, `post` in theme that does not support them out of the box, you need to put them into `_layouts` folder (create such one if not present).

Note that it may require more work than just sheer copying html file from another theme.